# Undefined variable at 'Incdntno.Value'

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, compiler-errors

I am having trouble getting this to compile, it keeps giving an undefined variable error during compile at 'Incdntno.Value'. I tried to Dim Incdntno as Integer but then was getting Invalid qualifier. I have a similar code that works (see second code block). I didn't need a lot of what was going in the working code part so I removed it. I would be so grateful if someone can point out where I am going wrong in the first code block? Thank you, very much

```
Private Sub Incdntno_AfterUpdate()
  Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim sSQL As String



  Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection


  If IsNull([Incdntno]) Then
    Me.Dirty = False
  End If
  Dim Incident As String
  Incident = Incdntno.Value
  sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblFieldIncident_Complaint_InspHist ( Incdntno, InspectID, Dt_Inspect ) SELECT " & [Incdntno] & ", " & [InspectID] & ", " & [InspDate] & " FROM tblInspect WHERE Incdntno='" & Incident & "';"
  conn.Execute sSQL
  'Me.Requery
  frmInspectItemsSub.Requery

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Code that works:

```
Private Sub InspectType_AfterUpdate()
  Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim sSQL As String
  Dim wYesNo As Integer
  On Error GoTo ProcErr

  If Not mbNewRecord Then
wYesNo = MsgBox("Changing the inspection type will erase the current entries and insert items specific to the new inspection. Proceed?", vbYesNo, "Inspection item update")
    If wYesNo <> vbYes Then GoTo ProcExit
  End If

   Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
  If Not mbNewRecord Then
conn.Execute "DELETE FROM tblInspectItems WHERE InspectID=" & InspectID
  End If

  If IsNull([InspectID]) Then
    Me.Dirty = False
  End If
  Dim inspType As String
  inspType = InspectType.Value
  sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblInspectItems ( ItemID, InspectID ) SELECT ItemID, " & [InspectID] & " FROM tblRefInspectItemCodes WHERE InspectType='" & inspType & "';"
  conn.Execute sSQL
  'Me.Requery
  frmInspectItemsSub.Requery

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

ProcErr:
  ErrMsg ("frmInspect.InspectType_AfterUpdate")
  Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a textbox or other control with the exact name `Incdntno` on your form already? Check in the properties viewer, Other tab.

Comment: Bound field(s)? Change name of 'Incident' to 'strIncident' and see if same error.

Comment: Pteranodon: I do have a textbox for Incdntno on the form, i checked it and it was called text56, i changed it to Incdntno and the compile error is gone! thanks, now I will see if my code works the way I want it to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like what happens if you duplicate event code. Take a close look at your control names and make sure they match. Also, you'll want to make sure that [Event Procedure] appears in the event properties. That link may not appear automatically if you change control names.

Comment: Can I only have one AfterUpdate Event?

Comment: I'm sorry. Each control *can* have an AfterUpdate event. I presumed that you copied `InspectType`'s AfterUpdate code, pasted it into the module, and then changed the sub's name to `Incdntno_AfterUpdate`. If you do this, the code is not immediately wired to the control. You need to click once on the control in design view, go to the properties, events, and drop down [Event Procedure] to make sure that it is connected.

Comment: I did that, its working 'sort of' now. see my new confusion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099645/type-mismatch-error-caused-by-where-clause-any-known-workarounds