# Type mismatch error caused by where clause, Any known workarounds?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Not sure why but I am getting type mismatch error when I execute this part of my Access  form. I checked the data types of all fields involved in SQL server, they are all matching. The InspectID and incdntno are both type 'INT' in both tables and the inspdate and Dt_inspect are 'datetime'.

I found that the mismatch is likely caused by the where clause of my query because the incdntno gets Dim'd as string (in SQL it's INT) I tried changing the datatype of Incdntno to varchar in both tables, thinking that that would survive the Dim to string and not cause a mismatch, I'm unsure if that worked because when I ran it next it threw an ODBC error.

```
Private Sub Text79_AfterUpdate()
  Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim sSQL As String

  Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection

  If IsNull([Incdntno]) Then
    Me.Dirty = False
  End If
  Dim InspNo As String
  InspNo = Incdntno.Value
  sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblFieldIncident_Complaint_InspHist ( Incdntno, InspectID, Dt_Inspect ) SELECT Incdntno, InspectID, InspDate FROM tblInspect WHERE Incdntno='" & InspNo & "';"
  conn.Execute sSQL
  Me.Refresh


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest leaving out the single quotes:

```
sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblFieldIncident_Complaint_InspHist( Incdntno, InspectID, Dt_Inspect )
          SELECT Incdntno, InspectID, InspDate
          FROM tblInspect
          WHERE Incdntno=" & InspNo & ";"
-------------------------^-------------^
```

Comment: Godron: the single quotes are for the SQL query, if i get rid of the single quotes, it errors back to 'data type mismatch for criteria expression'. I'm beginning to think there isn't away to get around this problem, unless I store numbers as text, but I'm pretty sure I don't want to do that. I need to dim the Incdntno as string to get the one I want (the one from the active form) into the Query but thats what is causing it to error

Comment: @Tom . . . The query should be fine (assuming that all that you say about the types is correct).  Perhaps there is an issue with your ODBC driver.  Do you have any other choices on how to connect to the database?

Comment: am I referencing the active field correctly? And Will it be in the backend database as soon as text gets entered into it? Maybe the AfterUpdate event is triggering before the data can get written to the Db causing an ODBC error. All other requests for data happen like they should and forms are populating so I know ODBC settings are good

Comment: @Tom . . . I am assuming that the column and tables names are correct.  You might remove the space before the paren (sometimes, databases have arcane issues with such things and I never use a space there).  An *after* update trigger should not affect data going into the database, unless it hangs and the transaction never closes (but I don't know if this applies to Access); the data has already (conceptually) gone into the table when an after trigger runs.